# Where to put extension dependencies in neo4j 3

Tags: java, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

Where should I be putting the plugin dependencies in neo4j 3 (not the actual plugin jars).

In neo4j 2 there was a lib folder where the system would load the jars from but this no longer exists.

I've tried putting them in the plugin folder but then it requires me to add every dependency of the jars which becomes unmanageable and it also seems weird to have them there.

I've tried putting them in the neo4j `bin` directory but they aren't detected.

I've tried adding a command line argument to the vmoptions file with a wildcard pointing to a lib folder I created and this didn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use maven shade plugin to package all the dependencies (except that one with scope test or provided) in the jar.

Comment: Does that means all runtime dependencies need to go in as well? If I have 2 plugins do I need duplicates? The spring bean jar I'm using has Groovy dependencies so this means I would have to bundle groovy in my jar. Is there no other way. What happened to the libs directory?

Answer (score 0):

I think the documentation has just been updated (although I may have missed it). It says

> Having built your code, the resulting jar file (and any custom dependencies) should be placed in the $NEO4J_SERVER_HOME/plugins directory. We also need to tell Neo4j where to look for the extension by adding some configuration in neo4j.conf:

So it turns out they should go in the plugins folder or you do as Daniela said and build a fat jar.

EDIT: I eventually came to the conclusion for several reasons including this one to use the server edition which has the same directory structure as the version 2.x.